# How to shift bytes of an NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsstring, arrays, aes

I have a NSString  like @"123456". I want to convert this string into byte array and then I want to shift some bytes using some arithmetic operations. Then I want to apply SHA256Hash on that and finally want to encrypt a string using the final result. I have tried many approaches but still got no success. I am very confused in this.If someone wants to look at code i'll post the code.

Edit:

My actual goal is to encrypt an string using AES256 encryption algorithm. And I want to generate my own key and I want to pass my own IV.

Comment: post your code please and tell us what's "wrong", I think we all can't tell what "success" means right now.

Comment: can you explain a bit more please ..not clear

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying achieve some kind of security. On the other hand it does not look like you're very familiar with the tools and methods you're using. This is a bad start.

Security is a **very** difficult thing to do—even for experienced developers. Maybe there's a way to reuse some existing implementation for your security needs.

My advice would be not to reinvent things, especially when they are as hard and as crucial as security.

Comment: you are right!. But I have some java code which I want to convert into objective-c code. In Java what they are doing is generating their own key using some byte shifting in a key and then doing sha256 on that key and then use that key encrypt message. I just need to convert their code into objective-c. If you want java code I have already posted but that question was closed by some moderators. Need help in this manner it's very urgent.